# How to compose a validation to check if one of two fields is not empty?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

So, in myForm, there are 2 fields name and email, I want to add the validation to check if the user input either one of them, it would pass the validation;
if both fields are null or empty, it fails.

How to compose such validators to meet my scenario?

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header my-contact-info">
                My Contact Info
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!myForm.controls['name'].valid && myForm.controls['name'].touched">This field is required.</small>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!myForm.controls['email'].valid && myForm.controls['email'].touched">This field is required. Please input a valid email.</small>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    buildForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        'name': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])],
        'email': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]
    });
}
```

Comment: You can check this on submit function with OR condition. If any one of them is given then execute your code else throw a validation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a custom validator for this, something like:

```
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export const OneFilledOutValidator = (): ValidatorFn => {

  return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: boolean} => {

    const fields = [];

    for (const field in group.controls) {

      if (group.controls.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        fields.push(group.get(field).value);
      }
    };

    const result = fields.filter(field => !!field);

    const valid = result.length !== 0;

    return valid ? null : {
      oneFilledOut: true
    };
  };
};
```

This basically takes a form group and checks if any of the controls has a value.

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
    'name': [null, [Validators.minLength(3)]],
    'email': [null, [Validators.email]]
}, OneFilledOutValidator); // I would wrap this in a CustomValidators constant
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad I literally just grabbed a quick example. No need to downvote over such a silly thing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Happy?

Comment: @AluanHaddad In the future, you can edit the answer yourself and add the first comment as the edit description. Instead of downvoting the entire answer because it's really misleading to the author of the question. There's nothing wrong with using any sometimes if the code itself works as expected.

Comment: Can you test it `const valid: boolean = Object.keys(group.controls).some((x => !!group.get(x).value);`? I'm on mobile and I can't test it now :D

Comment: @Chrillewoodz While you make a good general case, I see so much bad TypeScript coming out of the Angular community that it can be worth downvoting. `any` is almost always wrong in an inference context. It also doesn't make sense. Why do people write more code so they can have worse tooling and defeat the purpose of using TypeScript? In general, I only see this crap from Angular users and I think it is because the framework encourages misunderstanding of what types are (see the `interface Type` declaration for example)

Comment: @developer033 That would probably work as well. I can't test it now either :)

Comment: @AluanHaddad I realise that and there are factors as to why angular people are so poor at typescript. But that is completely unrelated to this question so I won't go into it. But like I said, you can always edit the answers and enlighten the author of the answer about what he or she is doing wrong. I always want to learn what I'm doing wrong but not in form of a downvote on a perfectly good answer. But rather in a better example and an explanation. :)

Comment: @Chrillewoodz well stated. I appreciate the spirit and the content of your remarks. :)

Comment: A complete example has also been posted here - http://brianflove.com/2016/10/16/dynamic-form-group-custom-validation-angular2/